# Can not set value of ace editor with template tags filters

Tags: django, django-templates, ace-editor

I have an ace editor in my html page,for which I can write

```
editor.setValue( '//Your code here');
```

It perfectly works and I get an editor with "//Your code here" written inside it.
But when I pass a template tag from django backend,with this line.

```
def func(request):
       context={"message":"hello there,write your code"}
       return render(request,'index.html',context)
```

and try to set value using template tagging filter with this line

```
editor.setValue({{message}});
```

It is not working,If I write it in simple html,It works,but not inside setValue() function.

Comment: The string is not wrapped within quotes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason that this does not work is because the message will not be wrapped within quotes.

You should make a JSON dump of the string that you pass to the template:

```
from json import dumps as jdumps

def func(request):
    context={'message': jdumps('hello there,write your code')}
    return render(request,'index.html',context)
```

and in the template, you should mark the string as safe with the [**`|safe`** template filter [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/templates/builtins/#safe) to prevent HTML-escaping the string:

```
editor.setValue({{ message|safe }});
```

Comment: You solved a ton of my work,I was thinking to change models.py etc etc. Really really thank you :)

Comment: I found an alternate solution today, 
context={'message':'this is a message'}
and in the html page use: "{{message|escapejs}}"